# How to shift elements in an array to the right?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop

I am new to programming and I am learning c++ now. 
I have an array of objects and I want to add a new object between two others. I have made a function that shifts the array at element index to the right but it seems that is deleting the other elements instead of only inserting the new element.

```
void Storage::ShiftProductsRight(int index)
{
    if(index == max_size - 1)
    {
        cout<<"No more place in storage! "<<endl;
        // array[max_size-1] = Product();
        return;
    }

    Product temp;
    for (int i = index + 1; i < max_size-1; ++i)
    {
        temp = array[max_size-1];
        array[max_size-1] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: C++ has `std::vector` that takes care of this for you.

Comment: Where in your code are you inserting a new element?

Comment: I think you *may* be looking for [std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)..?

Comment: How does comparing `index` with `max_size - 1` tell you that the array is full? An array could be full even if you are trying to insert at index 0.

Comment: Although I can see that the code is wrong it's hard to help because it's not clear what the variables mean. What is `max_size`?

Comment: "I have an array of objects and I want to add a new object" - a C-style array as well as a `std::array` have a fixed size that's set at compile time. They cannot grow. If you need a dynamic (growable) array, then you want [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Also, if you get all of those other issues sorted out, the easiest way to "make room" in the array is to start from the right end of the array (or wherever the "end of the array" is in your implementation) and go backwards in the loop, overwriting element `i` with element `i - 1`.

Comment: *"it seems that"* is not reassuring. Perhaps you could contrive a [mre] that shows elements being deleted? To keep things simple, you might want to use an array of `char` instead of an array of `Product`.

Answer (score 3):

> How to shift elements in an array to the right?

The algorithm to do this is: Start from the last element, move it to the new position, iterate backwards and repeat until the index where you're going to insert the new element

There is an implementation of this algorithm in the standard library. It is called [`std::move_backwards`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move_backward).

Comment: Please note: it's UB if you trying to perform the *in-place* shifting: 
"The behaviour is undefined if d_last is within (first, last]."
[SRC](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move_backward)